# Segfault at srandom_r

Tags: c, linux, random, reentrancy

I'm at my wits end. This trivial code gives me Segfault, what could be possibly wrong??

```
struct  random_data *qq;

qq = calloc(50, sizeof(struct random_data));
srandom_r(time(NULL), qq);
```

Now if I change it like this, it works:

```
struct  random_data qq;

srandom_r(time(NULL), &qq);
```

I must be a total moron, but I can't grasp it. Please, help.

Update: calloc returns a valid pointer

```
(uint64_t) 1aa5010
```

However, &qq represents the pointer

```
(uint64_t) 7fffbb428090
```

and that's the difference, but it's unclear why srandom_r fails to execute.
I try at Linux 2.6.32-44-server #98-Ubuntu

Comment: And the allocation didn't fail? And why are you allocating 50 `random_data` structures?

Comment: Use [valgrind](http://valgrind.org) on your program. Your memory might be much more corrupted than what you think and the bug is probably elsewhere in your code....

Answer (score 5, accepted):

it seems like most answers never actually tried to run your code.
here's a very minimalistic program, that indeed exhibits your problem:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>

int main() {
 int seed = time(NULL);
 struct random_data *qq = NULL;

 qq = calloc(1, sizeof(struct random_data));
 if(qq) {
   srandom_r(seed, qq); /* segfault! */
 } else {
   printf("failed to allocate `qq`\n");
 }
 return 0;
}
```

valgrind doesn't show much apart from an illegal memory access:

> ==22907== Invalid write of size 4
>   ==22907==    at 0x409CE8D: srandom_r (random_r.c:182)
>   ==22907==    by 0x80484A1: main (srand_ko.c:10)
>   ==22907==  Address 0x0 is not stack'd, malloc'd or (recently) free'd

now when looking at the `random_data` struct, you will find that it contains a pointer to a state-buffer:

```
struct random_data
  {
    int32_t *fptr;              /* Front pointer.  */
    int32_t *rptr;              /* Rear pointer.  */
    int32_t *state;             /* Array of state values.  */
    int rand_type;              /* Type of random number generator.  */
    int rand_deg;               /* Degree of random number generator.  */
    int rand_sep;               /* Distance between front and rear.  */
    int32_t *end_ptr;           /* Pointer behind state table.  */
  };
```

obviously all those pointers will be NULL if you allocate with `calloc()`, and `srandom_r` doesn't really like that.
you can help it be manually allocating an array of state values and assign it to the `random_data` struct using `initstate_r`.
since `initstate_r` already takes a `seed`, you don't need to call `srandom_r` anymore (but you can if you want to):

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>

#define STATESIZE 64
int main() {
 int seed = time(NULL);
 char*buf = (char*)calloc(STATESIZE, sizeof(char));
 struct random_data *qq = NULL;

 qq = calloc(1, sizeof(struct random_data));
 initstate_r(seed, buf, STATESIZE, qq);
 /* generate some random numbers */
 /* ... */

 srandom_r(seed, qq);
 /* generate the same random numbers again */
 /* ... */

 /* cleanup */
 free(buf);
 free(qq);
 return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your work on this - I appreciate really. Your last snippet shows fundamental discrepancy from what man random_r says: you allocate char*buf and the state is actually kept there, not in random_data structure. I am still not sure why &qq version worked then (where I didn't allocate memory - just declared _struct random_data qq_ locally). So far I'm just using random() in multi-threaded program (as i do not actually need per-thread reproducibility of random sequence)

Answer (score 2):

'random_data' does not contain the memory that holds the state of the random number generator - it holds the state the state is in....

The 'correct way' to use random_r is:

```
struct random_data rstate;
char random_bin[256];
initstate_r(MY_SEED,random_bin,256,&rstate);
```

Now you can call srandom_r and random_r.

There is no need to malloc or calloc anything, and doing so will slow you down as you will get cache misses everytime you go to generate a random number.

Comment: if done locally, rstate still needs to be initialized before initstate_r uses it.  otherwise, valgrind complains "Use of uninitialised value of size 8".  either `struct random_data rstate = {0};` or declaring rstate globally, where it gets automatically initialized, works

Answer (score 1):

You might like ot add a test whether `calloc()` succeeded, as passing `NULL` most propably provokes the segmentation violation.

```
#include <stdlib.h>

...

  struct random_data * qq = calloc(50, sizeof(*qq));
  if (NULL == qq)
    perror("malloc() failed");
  else
    srandom_r(time(NULL), qq);
```

Comment: @wick Then you might want to edit your question to include a more complete example, preferably a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/). Because the code as shown in the question should work fine (if the allocation succeeds that is).

Comment: @wick: `<stdlib.h>` is `#include`d in the module in question?

Comment: @alk yes, would it compile otherwise?

Comment: @wick: If not expliclitly told to treat warnings as errors the compiler surely could translate the code, giving warnings about implicitly declaring `calloc()`, `srandom_r()`, .... However if on a 64bit OS at least the value returned by `calloc()` could very well be crippled though.

Comment: @wick: Ok, if all necessary includes are in place, I'd tend to say you observe the outcome of a memory managment corruption due to having overwritten memory in some code having run prior to this one. To test this you might like to run your program under a memory checker like for example Valgrind: http://valgrind